# Akamai cache clear/refresh and its APIs

Tags: caching, cdn, akamai

We're using Akamai system as CDN and using Cache Clear/purging function of it to clear the cached assets. Whenever we deploy static/any content on Apache we do manual cache clear from Akamai portal. This manual activity is missed sometimes. We're looking for some options wherein once deployment is done it triggers the Akamai cache clear.

Is there any API available in Akamai which we can utilize for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Akamai does provide an API for clearing the cache. It's called the [Content Control Utility v3](https://developer.akamai.com/api/purge/ccu/overview.html). There are several other versions of the Purge API set, but the CCU v3 is the recommended API against which you should work.

If you require any assistance in implementing that particular API, Akamai also maintains a [Customer Community](https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/content) where you can work directly with Akamai employees.

Comment: Appreciate your help Josh. Thank you for giving the details. :)